# Lighting-techniques tag should be merged

Tags: support, tags

There's a nice schema of lighting-* tags, and the barely-used and undescribed [lighting-techniques](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lighting-techniques) seems superfluous.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds good to me. The tag doesn't seem to add much over just plain "lighting". There were under a dozen, so I just retagged them all. (The tag should therefore go away tomorrow.)